# How can I read csv in python as a list without string (see exapmle below)?

Tags: python, list, csv

**CSV in Editor looks:**

```
Review Text;Review Rating
['much', 'write', 'exactly', 'supposed', 'filters', 'pop', 'sounds', 'recordings', 'much', 'crisp', 'one', 'lowest', 'prices', 'pop', 'filters', 'amazon', 'might', 'well', 'buy', 'honestly', 'work', 'despite', 'pricing'];5.0
```

**Read CSV:**

```
import csv

with open("../Data_filtered/reviews_Musical_Instruments.csv", "r") as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';', quotechar='|')
    liste = []
    for row in reader:
        liste.extend(row)
```

**Then I get:**

```
liste = 
['Review Text',
 'Review Rating',
 "['much', 'write', 'exactly', 'supposed', 'filters', 'pop', 'sounds', 'recordings', 'much', 'crisp', 'one', 'lowest', 'prices', 'pop', 'filters', 'amazon', 'might', 'well', 'buy', 'honestly', 'work', 'despite', 'pricing']",
 '5.0']
```

**But I need (without string):**

```
liste = 
['Review Text',
 'Review Rating', 'much', 'write', 'exactly', 'supposed', 'filters', 'pop', 'sounds', 'recordings', 'much', 'crisp', 'one', 'lowest', 'prices', 'pop', 'filters', 'amazon', 'might', 'well', 'buy', 'honestly', 'work', 'despite', 'pricing',
 '5.0']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to parse it, using [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) is a good choice:

```
import csv
import ast

with open("../Data_filtered/reviews_Musical_Instruments.csv", "r") as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';', quotechar='|')
    liste = []
    for row in reader:
        row[2] = ast.literal_eval(row[2])
        liste.extend(row)
```